# How to train a single neural network model on many sets of time series data without concatenating in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I would like to build a neural network that acts as a surrogate model for an engineering system: given 1 input (e.g. step input) it predicts 1 output (e.g. displacement) using Tensorflow.

I have many sets of data of varying lengths that I would like to train my neural network on. The datasets represent different conditions that the system may experience, so it is important that the network learns all possible scenarios. All data is consecutive time series of readings taken in different experiments, so I cannot concatenate it into one set.

So far I am building my model and then calling datasets in loop and calling model.fit.

I have read elsewhere that calling model.fit consecutively doesn't erase previous training but adds to it -- is this correct? The code is provided below.

```
directory = Path(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Mass_Spring_Damper') # Raw training files directory
column_names = ['Time', 'Displacement', 'Step input'] # Time column, output column, input column

# Create model
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=200,
                    activation='relu',
                    return_sequences=True,
                    kernel_regularizer=L1L2(l1=0.01, l2=0.0),
                    input_shape=(None, 1)))

model.add(Dense(1,
                activation='linear'))

# Compile model with optimizer
optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3, clipvalue=1)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)

model.summary()

# Train model over multiple datasets in loop
for file in directory.glob('*.csv'):

    dataset = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False, names=column_names)

    # Parse time column as datetime
    s = dataset['Time']
    start = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0)  # Reference date, choose any!
    datetime_series = s.astype('timedelta64[s]') + start
    time_series = datetime_series.dt.time
    dataset = dataset.drop(['Time'], axis=1)
    dataset.insert(0, 'Time', time_series, True)  # Insert datetime column into raw dataset
    dataset['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
    dataset = dataset.set_index('Time')

    # Drop NaN values
    dataset = dataset.dropna()

    # Train-test-validation split
    train_dataset, test_dataset = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(dataset,
                                                                           test_size=0.1,
                                                                           shuffle=False,
                                                                           random_state=42)

    train_dataset, val_dataset = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(train_dataset,
                                                                          test_size=0.2,
                                                                          shuffle=False,
                                                                          random_state=42)


    # Define input and target signals
    input_signals = ['Step input']
    target_signals = ['Displacement']

    # Get x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, x_val, y_val
    train_dataset_input = train_dataset[input_signals]
    x_train = train_dataset_input.values

    train_dataset_target = train_dataset[target_signals]
    y_train = train_dataset_target.values

    test_dataset_input = test_dataset[input_signals]
    x_test = test_dataset_input.values

    test_dataset_target = test_dataset[target_signals]
    y_test = test_dataset_target.values

    val_dataset_input = val_dataset[input_signals]
    x_val = val_dataset_input.values

    val_dataset_target = val_dataset[target_signals]
    y_val = val_dataset_target.values

    # Find and replace invalid data in arrays
    x_train[x_train < 1e-9] = 0
    y_train[y_train < 1e-9] = 0
    x_test[x_test < 1e-9] = 0
    y_test[y_test < 1e-9] = 0
    x_val[x_val < 1e-9] = 0
    y_val[y_val < 1e-9] = 0

    train_size = len(x_train)  # Size of training set (used later for input generator)
    num_x_signals = x_train.shape[1]  # Number of input signals
    num_y_signals = y_train.shape[1]  # Number of output signals

    # Scale data
    x_scaler = MinMaxScaler((0, 1))
    x_train_scaled = x_scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
    x_test_scaled = x_scaler.transform(x_test)
    x_val_scaled = x_scaler.transform(x_val)

    y_scaler = MinMaxScaler((0, 1))
    y_train_scaled = y_scaler.fit_transform(y_train)
    y_test_scaled = y_scaler.transform(y_test)
    y_val_scaled = y_scaler.transform(y_val)

    # Random training batch generator 
    def batch_generator(batch_size, sequence_length):
        
        while True:
            # Allocate a new array for the batch of input-signals.
            x_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_x_signals)
            x_batch = np.zeros(shape=x_shape, dtype=np.float16)

            # Allocate a new array for the batch of output-signals.
            y_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length, num_y_signals)
            y_batch = np.zeros(shape=y_shape, dtype=np.float16)

            # Fill the batch with random sequences of data.
            for i in range(batch_size):
                # Get a random start-index.
                # This points somewhere into the training-data.
                idx = np.random.randint(train_size - sequence_length)

                # Copy the sequences of data starting at this index.
                x_batch[i] = x_train_scaled[idx:idx + sequence_length]
                y_batch[i] = y_train_scaled[idx:idx + sequence_length]

            yield (x_batch, y_batch)

    batch_size = 128
    sequence_length = 50
    generator = batch_generator(batch_size=batch_size, sequence_length=sequence_length)

    # Callbacks
    path_checkpoint = '23_checkpoint.keras'
    callback_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=path_checkpoint,
                                          monitor='val_loss',
                                          verbose=1,
                                          save_weights_only=True,
                                          save_best_only=True)  # Callback for writing checkpoints during training

    callback_early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                            patience=5,
                                            verbose=1)  # Callback for stopping optimization when performance worsens on validation set

    callback_reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',
                                           factor=0.1,
                                           min_lr=1e-5,
                                           patience=0,
                                           verbose=1)  # Callback for reducing learning rate when validation loss does not improve

    callbacks = [callback_checkpoint, callback_reduce_lr, callback_early_stopping]

    # Define validation data
    validation_data = (np.expand_dims(x_val_scaled, axis=0), np.expand_dims(y_val_scaled, axis=0))

    # Train model
    history = model.fit(x=generator,
                        epochs=100,
                        validation_data=validation_data,
                        callbacks=callbacks,
                        steps_per_epoch=50)
```

Is this a valid way of training a network on many sets of data to ensure it learns all possible behavior of the real system?

Comment: What is the problem with concatenating the data?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a correct approach as each of my sets is a separate experiment with readings taken each second from 0 to 30,000 seconds. Would my batch size need to be 30,000 in that case? To avoid shuffling the data.

Comment: Again, there is no reason why it would not work, you seem to be making incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Yes, I assumed I could only take random batches for training from one experiment at a time, but thinking about it now maybe that is an unfounded assumption. Would you say that concatenating large amounts of data into very large datasets the most acceptable approach among experts?

Comment: just an explanation to @Dr. Snoopy. Concatenating the data would work but I think as time series are values where a given time depend on the previous one (values are not independent), if we concatenate we would be assuming that the start of a batch depends on de end of the previous batch. That would create an error, specially if the sets of data are small and there are many.

Comment: @eliasmaxil You would be concatenating along the samples dimension, not time or sequence dimensions.